# Error in > or < symbol in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My code is :

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = 'Before 91-150 days'

-- Chop off the end character
SET @String = 
      CASE @String 
         WHEN null THEN null 
         ELSE (CASE LEN(@String) 
                  WHEN 0 THEN @String           
                  WHEN (charindex('-',(SUBSTRING(@String, charindex(' ', @String), CHARINDEX(' ', @String) - 3))) > 0) THEN --(shows error in >)
                        SUBSTRING(@String, charindex(' ', @String), CHARINDEX(' ', @String) - 4) - 1 
                  WHEN (charindex('-', SUBSTRING(@String, charindex(' ', @String), CHARINDEX(' ', @String) - 3)) < 0) THEN --(shows error in <)
                        SUBSTRING(@String, charindex(' ', @String), CHARINDEX(' ', @String) - 3) - 1
               END) 
      END

SELECT @String
```

Error is :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near '>'.

I don't know what I am doing wrong...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server management studio 2014.

Comment: And what should be the output of this case in your example?

Comment: If string is 'Before 91-150 days' , output should be 90 and if string is 'Before 61-90 days' then output should be 60. so in short the output should be (lower limit -1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `case`s don't make sense. The first one is `when 0` but the second one is a boolean. Make them both use an `int` by moving the first `LEN` inside the `WHEN`:

```
CASE 
    WHEN LEN(@String) = 0 
        THEN @String          
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(@String, charindex(' ',@String), CHARINDEX(' ',@String)-3), 0) > 0
        THEN --Other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code lacks substrings/replacements

```
SUBSTRING(@String, charindex(' ', @String), CHARINDEX(' ', @String) - 4)
```

You don't use `'-'` position here. First and second `CHARINDEX` will point to the same `' '` (position 7) - that's why this code makes totally no sense at all

`SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

You could fix it by code which

1. at first takes substring from first space till the end of string,
2. takes substring of the string obtained in stage 1 from the beginning of it till the first space (second space in original string given)
3. searches for '-' delimiter and uses devided string parts

so your code needs at least two substring.

try this:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = 'Before 91-150 days'


SET @String = LTRIM(REPLACE(@String, 'before', ''))

SELECT @String

IF CHARINDEX('-', @String) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @String = LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX('-', @String)-1)
    SELECT @String

    SELECT TRY_CAST(@String AS INT)-1
END
```

or

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = 'Before 91-150 days'

SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('-', LTRIM(REPLACE(@String, 'before', ''))) > 0
        THEN TRY_CAST(LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(@String, 'before', '')), CHARINDEX('-',  LTRIM(REPLACE(@String, 'before', '')))-1) AS INT)-1
        ELSE @String
    END
```

both with prints:

```
GO
PRINT 'test-1'

DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = 'Before 91-150 days'


SET @String = LTRIM(REPLACE(@String, 'before', ''))

PRINT @String

IF CHARINDEX('-', @String) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @String = LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX('-', @String)-1)
    PRINT @String

    PRINT TRY_CAST(@String AS INT)-1
END
PRINT '==='

GO
PRINT 'test-2'

DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = 'Before 91-150 days'

PRINT 
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('-', LTRIM(REPLACE(@String, 'before', ''))) > 0
        THEN TRY_CAST(LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(@String, 'before', '')), CHARINDEX('-',  LTRIM(REPLACE(@String, 'before', '')))-1) AS INT)-1
        ELSE @String
    END 

PRINT '==='
GO
```

output:

```
test-1
91-150 days
91
90
===
test-2
90
===
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. but if i write this query:                              select SUBSTRING('Before 51-120 days',charindex(' ','Before 51-120 days'),CHARINDEX(' ','Before 51-120 days'))                                          It returns 51-120, so it means that both charindex are not returning the same value.Let me know if i am wrong.

Comment: I guess first charindex is returning the starting value and second charindex is returning the value till you want the string(end value).

Comment: `SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length ) ` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: `select SUBSTRING('b 51-120 days',charindex(' ','b 51-120 days'),CHARINDEX(' ','b 51-120 days'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = 'Before 91-150 days'

-- Chop off the end character
SET @String = 
      CASE  WHEN @String IS NULL 
            THEN null 
            WHEN LEN(@String)= 0 
            THEN @String          
            WHEN (charindex('-',(SUBSTRING(@String,charindex(' ',@String),CHARINDEX(' ',@String)-3))) > 0) 
            THEN SUBSTRING(@String,charindex(' ',@String),CHARINDEX(' ',@String)-4) -1 
            WHEN (charindex('-',SUBSTRING(@String,charindex(' ',@String),CHARINDEX(' ',@String)-3)) < 0) 
            THEN SUBSTRING(@String,charindex(' ',@String),CHARINDEX(' ',@String)-3) -1
       END 


SELECT @String
```